# json and javascript getting value

Tags: jquery, json

How would I be able to get the username in jquery from the following

```
{"id":true,"username":"mynameisdonald"}
```

I have tried console.log(data); which shows the above and when i use console.log(data.username) it shows as undefined

Comment: is this a string or an actual JSON Object? are you assigning it to variable data at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) function:

```
var jsonStr = '{"id":true,"username":"mynameisdonald"}';
var obj = $.parseJSON(jsonStr);
console.log(obj.username);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your jQuery call, specify that this is JSON:

```
$.post(
    "backend.php", 
    data: "nodata",
    function(data) {
        console.log(data.username);
    },
    "json"
);
```

or use jQuery's [`parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) like so:

```
$.post(
    "backend.php", 
    data: "nodata",
    function(rawData) {
        var data = $.parseJSON(rawData);
        console.log(data.username);
    }
);
```